# c++ if statement not working as expected, printing "else" before asking for input

Tags: c++, if-statement, getline

So, I was writing this question in c++

```
    cout << "Would you like the answer in Joules or eV?" << endl;
    cout << "Type 'j' or 'e' to make the selection" << endl;
    invalid = true;
    while (invalid) { //This while loop repeats the question until the user enters e or j
        invalid = false;
        getline(cin, units);
        if (units == "e"|| units == "E") {
            answer = energy(Z,n1,n2);
            cout << "The answer is: " << answer << " eV" << endl;
        }
        else if (units == "j"|| units == "J" || units == "joules" || units == "joule") {
            answer = energy_j(Z,n1,n2);
            cout << "The answer is: " << answer << " J" << endl;    
        }
        else {
            cout << "Please enter either j or e, and press enter." << endl;
            invalid = true;
        }
    }
```

and it seemed fine, but for some reason it always prints the "else" bit when I run it. I have the exact same code below and it runs fine. Can anyone help? (I'm compiling with g++ on linux, if that makes a difference)

The code runs fine, but I'd like to know about why this small bug is happening. The output is shown below:

```
Would you like the answer in Joules or eV?
Type 'j' or 'e' to make the selection
Please enter either j or e, and press enter.
k
Please enter either j or e, and press enter.
e
```

Edit: So you can see how variables are defined, etc. [Link to full code here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6850213/)

Comment: What is the type of variable `units`? Also where did the variable `selection` came from?

Comment: Do you have other input further up in the program? (in particular, with `std::cin >> something`)

Comment: I've never seen `std::getline` used on `std::cin`... It might still work, but that looks fishy to me.  Try `std::cin >>units` or [`std::cin.getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

Comment: It's not 'printing "else"' at all. It is printing whatever the 'else' block prints. Please correct your title.

Comment: @Proxy from your link: `The first version is equivalent to getline(s, count, widen('\n'))`. There's nothing fishy about it.

Comment: @Proxy What's fishy about it.  `std:::cin` can be used where ever an `std::istream` can be used.

Comment: I'd add at least a check that the `getline` worked.

Comment: You're not responding to us which makes it harder to solve the issue. Have you tried `std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` before `std::getline`?

Comment: @Proxy You can see it here -> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: I don't see the definition of `units`. The problem is probably there.

Comment: I don't know if the "You're not responding to us which makes it harder to solve the issue" was directed at me, but I posted this then went to a lecture, so sorry about that. I'm back now and I'm pleased you've all responded so quickly and kindly. Thank you. There's some confusion about how I've defined variables so I shall edit the question with a link to the full code so you can see how they're defined. Thank you again for your continued help.
Full code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6849906/

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks for the suggestion, indeed adding:  
    `cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`  
before the getline() solved the issue. Can anyone explain why this solution works, and why the code was incorrect to begin with. Can anyone suggest improved code that does a better job of getting the user's input?

Comment: @captainjamie I'll post an answer in a minute.

Comment: This is taking more than a minute, sorry! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### The problem:

The last extraction you performed before the call to `std::getline()` was:

> ```
> while (!(cin >> n2))
> {
>     cout << "Please enter a number for the final state" << endl;
>     cin.clear();
>     cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
> }
> ```

Which is perfectly fine. The only problem is that, given a valid extraction, the newline character `'\n'` will be left in the stream. By default, the unformatted input function `std::getline()` delimits input upon the acquisition of a newline character. If the residual newline is still left in the stream, the input cannot be performed.

<sub>Note that technically `std::getline()` discards the character but ceases extraction once it is found.</sub>

---

> #### The solution:

The solution I suggested in the comments section of your question was to execute the following lines of code above your unformatted extraction:

> ```
> std::cin.clear();
> std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
> ```

What this does in order is clear the underlying stream state (a bitmask that represents errors during I/O) and ignore the maximum amount of characters until the next newline character is found (it also consumes the newline).

> **Why did I suggest this?**

If the stream state has a bit turned on (either `failbit`, `eofbit`, or `badbit`) the stream won't be able to perform I/O (this also includes ignoring characters). The `ignore()` call is used to discard any residual input until we reach the end of the line, so we have a fresh new line to restart input.

However, since you updated your post showing me the full code, I now realize that those two calls are not needed as you already took care of invalid input in the first code example I showed you. Moreover, since you made sure the most recent extraction succeeded, there's no need to reset the stream state.

Instead, what I propose is to use the manipulator `std::ws` which will discard all whitespace characters (newline is also considered whitespace) until a non-whitespace character is found. It is a much more idiomatic approach to discarding newlines:

> ```
> std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, units);
> //           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

This should be equivalent to the `ignore()` call because all that's left in the stream is a newline.

> #### Improvements:

Here are a few:

1. The first is to always check if your input succeeded:

   > ```
   > if (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, units))
   > {
   >     //
   > }
   > ```
2. If `units` will always be one character, then just use a character:

   > ```
   > char units;
   > if (std::cin >> units)
   > {
   >     if (units == 'e' || ... )
   > }
   > ```

Comment: "You're performing a comparison on selection before it was given a value."  
That was an unrelated typo. Corrected now, thanks.

Comment: @captainjamie Also note that unlike unformatted input operators (like `getline`) formatted input operators like `operator>>` discard new lines from the beginning of the stream before performing input. That's why I didn't have to do `std::cin >> std::ws >> units` in the last code snippet.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this code (http://paste.ubuntu.com/6850301/) works fine now. Thank you for your help. I couldn't get it to compile when I changed `units` and `selection` to `char`, so I kept them as `string`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `std::cin.clear();` before the getline.

Comment: No! He's saying that the `if`/`else if`/`else` is being entered **before he provides any input**.

Comment: oh I see, sorry, I misunderstood the question. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe print out units before the if to see what it is holding. I would personally do the following to get input :

```
    string units;
    cin >> units;
```